# Como tornar global uma variável local em C (ou C++)?

Tags: c, c++

Eu consigo fazer uma variável local se transformar em global, mesmo ela estando dentro de uma função? Na linguagem C ou mesmo C++ se não existir na C. Já vi algo do tipo em Java, mas não sei exatamente como funciona.

Comment: Por que não declarar logo a variável do lado de fora?

Comment: Porque eu preciso que ela guarde um valor de uma função. Sendo que o usuário que vai informar esse valor

Comment: Não entendi. Isso não impede a variável de ser global. Além disso, por que não simplesmente retornar o valor lido?

Comment: Assim existe uma função que pede ao usuário para informar o tamanho de um vetor e esse tamanho deve ser acessível de todas outras funções.

Comment: @MarcosAdriano então é só fazer o que o Pablo disse, declarar fora da função. Seria mais legal você colocar o código na pergunta, até pra gente te ajudar a não fazer gambiarra. Fica mais fácil você explicar qual é o problema real que quer resolver, e não se limitar à maneira que acha que é a solução. Inclusive, esse negócio de querer solução em C e C++ dá uma impressão meio estranha. Decidir qual linguagem vai usar com base nessa questão específica é sinal de problema.

Comment: Você não precisa declarar uma variável apenas no local no qual ela vai receber um valor. A variável pode ser global (declarada do lado de fora) e você atribui o valor a ela nessa função. Desde que você chame essa função antes das outras, não vai ter problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Faça como todos falaram, ou ainda melhor, declare fora do escopo da função e como static.

```
static int variavel=0;

void X()
{
      variavel++;
}
int main()
{
     cout << variavel; 
     variavel ++;
     cout << variavel;
     X();
     cout << variavel;
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A única maneira (até aonde eu conheço) de você possuir uma variável global em C é declarando ela fora de qualquer função, como qualquer outra variável global.

Imagino que o que você esteja querendo é declarar uma variável local com o comportamento de uma variável global, com as limitações de escopo. Para isso utilize a palavra `static`.

```
void funcao(){
    static int k = 0;
    k++;
    printf("%d\n", k);
}
```

Ao chamar a função 3 vezes, ela irá imprimir:

```
1
2
3
```

A explicação para isso se deve ao fato de que, ao declarar uma variável local como static, ela será armazenada em outro local de memória. Sempre que há uma chamada de função é gerada o chamado **call stack**, nela é reservada um espaço para guardar os valores das variáveis locais e, ao sair da função, a região é liberada. Ao utilizar o static, a variável é alocada em outro local.

Há uma leitura interessante sobre pilha de chamada de funções, caso tenha interesse: [BufferOverflow](http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow2a.html)

Recomendo: [Static: The Multipurpose Keyword](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html)

Comment: Exatamente essa era a minha dúvida Murillo Henrique, fazer ela se comportar como uma global mesmo estando dentro de uma função. Mas com isso poderei acessá-la de de qualquer função ?

Comment: Outra coisa também, essa implementação funciona em Linguagem C ?

Comment: Não, você não poderá acessar de outro local, apenas dentro da função. A única coisa que muda é que o valor da variável não é perdida ao sair da função pois ela está em outro local de memória e não na pilha de chamada de funções. O exemplo que eu passei funciona em C, lembrando que se você usar a palavra static em uma variável global ou função você estará restringindo o acesso a ela para outros arquivos, a palavra static tem usos diferentes dependendo de onde ela é usada